# accessing a set of values from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary in python that is statically initialized as shown below

```
switch_port_to_host = {
                's1-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:01',
                's4-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                's2-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                's5-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:05',
                's3-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:03',
                's6-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:06'
               };
```

How do I get the mac-addresses alone inside a loop.Basically I want to be able to print out

```
00:00:00:00:00:01
00:00:00:00:00:02
00:00:00:00:00:03
00:00:00:00:00:04
00:00:00:00:00:05
00:00:00:00:00:06
```

How do I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict = {
                's1-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:01',
                's4-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                's2-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                's5-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:05',
                's3-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:03',
                's6-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:06'
        }


# get values 
print dict.values()


#by lines
for value in dict.values():
    print value
```

`values()` gets your the values of your dictionary called `dict`.

**Output** as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `switch_port_to_host`, it'll give you the key then print the value of the key

```
switch_port_to_host = {
                's1-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:01',
                's4-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                's2-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:02',
                's5-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:05',
                's3-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:03',
                's6-eth1':'00:00:00:00:00:06'
               };

for i in switch_port_to_host:
    print switch_port_to_host[i]
```

Comment: Enumerate or iterate?

Comment: @thefourtheye my bad sorry

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 switch_port_to_host.values()
```

To get the set of values as a `list`.

You can print them on separate lines using:

```
for x in switch_port_to_host.values():
    print x
```